# Python, context sensitive string substitution

Tags: python, regex, string-substitution

Is it possible to do something like this in Python using regular expressions?

> Increment every character that is a number in a string by 1

So input "123ab5" would become "234ab6"

I know I could iterate over the string and manually increment each character if it's a number, but this seems unpythonic.

note. This is not homework. I've simplified my problem down to a level that sounds like a homework exercise.

Comment: What happens with a `9`?

Comment: @eumiro wraps to zero i guess, didn't think of that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = "123ab5"

b = ''.join(map(lambda x: str(int(x) + 1) if x.isdigit() else x, a))
```

or:

```
b = ''.join(str(int(x) + 1) if x.isdigit() else x for x in a)
```

or:

```
import string
b = a.translate(string.maketrans('0123456789', '1234567890'))
```

In any of these cases:

```
# b == "234ab6"
```

**EDIT** - the first two map `9` to a `10`, the last one wraps it to `0`. To wrap the first two into zero, you will have to replace `str(int(x) + 1)` with `str((int(x) + 1) % 10)`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> test = '123ab5'
>>> def f(x):
        try:
            return str(int(x)+1)
        except ValueError:
            return x
 >>> ''.join(map(f,test))
     '234ab6'
```

Comment: ops, same solution.. i think you was faster than me

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = "123ab5"
>>> def foo(n):
...     try: n = int(n)+1
...     except ValueError: pass
...     return str(n)
... 
>>> a = ''.join(map(foo, a))
>>> a
'234ab6'
```

by the way with a simple if or with try-catch eumiro solution with join+map is the more pythonic solution for me too